# Selectize like component for expo, react-native or flutter

Tags: react-native, flutter

Does React Native (or Flutter) have a component that works like the seletize.js jQuery plugin?

Requirements are,

1. Multi-select
2. Retrieve multiple options remotely from an API

I'm currently using selectize inside an Ionic project and I want to leave Ionic for its many performance and compatibility issues.

Comment: Expo is not technically a development framework. Also, please use correct tags.It seems you're looking for RN and have tagged flutter and expo.

Comment: Is this something you are looking for? https://github.com/toystars/react-native-multiple-select

Comment: @SebbeBerglönn, yes. But unfortunately, that plugin doesn't support fetching from remote APIs.

Comment: @AthulRaj, but you can make your own request and then insert that array into the list. So it is absolutely usable in your case